# Installation failed with message null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

I have a problem with android studio and genymotion.
I have a AMD processor that doesn't not support vt-x that is why i use genymotion.
When I try to launch my simple app I get this error:

> Installation failed with message null.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>   WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>   Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

I have:
Windows 7
Android Studio 2.1.2
VirtualBox 5.0.20

Please need some help !

Answer (score 0):

Disable instant run in android studio.

Answer (score -1):

It's because the emulator already has the app you're trying to install. Uninstall the app then reinstall it. 
Otherwise, disable instant run.